# Tweets Data set for Topic Detection Classification Model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-classification

I am trying to make a model that works like the new feature "topics" in Twitter. How ever I cannot find a data set I can use, does anyone have an idea how I can get this data set?

Comment: Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for this data on Google. If no luck there, Please try to use twitter RESTful API to access twitter data with Python. You can find some code online. Even that doesn't works for you, you can export your own tweets from Twitter. For more help, please this link - https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/accessing-your-twitter-data
Hope this is helpful.